# How can I render a different view for a subpath of a route in Express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on a Node js + Express + express-handlebars application. In my **app.js** file I am defining my routes as

```
var students = require('./routes/students');
var faculty = require('./routes/faculty');

app.use('/students', students);
app.use('/faculty', faculty);
```

Where **students.js** and **faculty.js** are present in the routes folder. So when the user goes to a path with /students, I do the following in the students.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('students_view', {
        msg : 'this is student page'
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Where `students_view` is an express-handlebars page in views folder. Now let's say I want to add a new student and when I press the Add button on the **student_view** page it takes me to a page with this url: /students/add

On that page, I need to render a different view (a form to be precise). In my app.js I am doing the following:

```
app.use('/student/add', students);
```

And in my student.js I am doing the following:

```
router.get('/add', function(req, res){
   res.render('students_add', {
        msg : 'this is student add page'
    });
 });
```

However, it still goes to the earlier router.get('/') and renders the student_view page. How do I render a different view for this path? Would it require its own separate route (say student_add.js) where I can handle the get and post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are consuming routes in `app.js`. change your `student.js` to

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('students_view', {
        msg : 'this is student page'
    });
});
router.get('/add', function(req, res){
   res.render('students_add', {
        msg : 'this is student add page'
    });
 });
```

and `app.js` to

```
app.use('/students', students); 
// not need of app.use('/students/add', students);
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete `app.use('/student/add', students);` in your `app.js`.
Just write `/students` route in `/routes/students.js`

`app.use('/students', students);` hold all urls like below:

    `/students
    /students/foo
    /students/foo/bar
...`

unless you write a route like `app.use('/students/baz', anotherStudentsRoute);` before `app.use('/students', students);`.